# findElement after switching webviews not working

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a simple Espresso test for Android that works okay until the Activity is switched.  The test runs through a login, selecting elements from a webview by class and then after a successful login, the activity switches.  Once in the new Activity, I am unable to find anything in the new webview, either by class, css selector or by x_path.

I know this is buried in the html, I can see it and search for it in the chrome insepctor:

```
<div _ngcontent-c9="" class="tile-title" title="Pay">Pay </div>
```

Yet I can't find it with this CSS_SELECTOR:

```
onWebView(allOf<View>(isDisplayed(), isJavascriptEnabled()))
                    .withElement(findElement(Locator.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[title=Pay]"))
```

Similarly, I have also tried with an X_PATH string and even by class name (which is not unique) but it still fails.

We do have multiple webviews created, but only one is visible.

What can I do to shed more light on this and figure out why I can't select the div in question?

**Update**

It appears I had missed something in the the log that revealed part of my problem.  I was seeing a `AmbiguousViewMatcherException` in the log.

Looking at the code, we have a FrameLayout with the name `web_container` and attach 3 webviews to the view with an `addView()` call.  So this component ends up having 3 children.

I changed the test to use `withParent()` and `isDisplayed()` to match the webview.  This call was throwing the exception before, but is now passing.

```
onWebView(allOf(withParent(withId(R.id.web_container)), isDisplayed())).forceJavascriptEnabled()
```

Given this success, I still can't find anything inside this webview, here is the modified onWebVeiw statement:

```
onWebView(allOf(withParent(withId(R.id.web_container)), isDisplayed())).forceJavascriptEnabled()

 Log.d("FeatureTest", "passed forceJavaScriptEnabled()")    
onWebView(allOf(withParent(withId(R.id.web_container)), isDisplayed()))
                        .withElement(findElement(Locator.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[title=Pay]")).perform(webClick())
```

The error I see in the logs:

```
09-21 09:19:19.490  9481  9529 D FeatureTest: Key: Mobile, with visibility: 0
09-21 09:19:19.490  9481  9529 D FeatureTest: Key: RDBX, with visibility: 4
09-21 09:19:19.490  9481  9529 D FeatureTest: Key: DEFAULT, with visibility: 4
09-21 09:19:19.496  9481  9481 I ViewInteraction: Performing 'Forcibly enable javascript.' action on view (has parent matching: with id: com.package.android.debug:id/web_container and is displayed on the screen to the user)
09-21 09:19:19.496  9481  9529 D FeatureTest: passed forceJavaScriptEnabled()
09-21 09:19:19.499  9481  9481 I ViewInteraction: Performing 'Evaluate Atom: android.support.test.espresso.web.webdriver.DriverAtoms$FindElementTransformingAtom@7c99c3e in window: null with element: null' action on view (has parent matching: with id: com.package.android.debug:id/web_container and is displayed on the screen to the user)
0

09-21 09:19:29.505  9481  9481 I ViewInteraction: Performing 'Propagate: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Waited 10 seconds for android.support.test.espresso.web.internal.deps.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$TransformFuture@8c677ec[status=PENDING, info=[inputFuture=[android.support.test.espresso.web.internal.deps.guava.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@19327b5[status=PENDING]], function=[android.support.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction$3@cbf3e4a]]]' action on view (has parent matching: with id: com.package.android.debug:id/web_container and is displayed on the screen to the user)
09-21 09:19:29.515  9481  9529 D FeatureTest: java.lang.RuntimeException@89926d8[cause=java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Waited 10 seconds for android.support.test.espresso.web.internal.deps.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$TransformFuture@8c677ec[status=PENDING, info=[inputFuture=[android.support.test.espresso.web.internal.deps.guava.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@19327b5[status=PENDING]], function=[android.support.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction$3@cbf3e4a]]],detailMessage=java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Waited 10 seconds for android.support.test.espresso.web.internal.deps.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$TransformFuture@8c677ec[status=PENDING, info=[inputFuture=[android.support.test.espresso.web.internal.deps.guava.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@19327b5[status=PENDING]], function=[android.support.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction$3@cbf3e4a]]],stackTrace={},suppressedExceptions=[]]
09-21 09:19:29.516  9481  9481 W e.android.debu: Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/Activity;->mResultCode:I (light greylist, reflection)
09-21 09:19:29.517  9481  9481 W e.android.debu: Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/Activity;->mResultData:Landroid/content/Intent; (light greylist, reflection)
09-21 09:19:29.517  9481  9529 I TestRunner: failed: testFeature(com.package.android.ui.FeatureTest)
```

Comment: Did you call `onWebView().forceJavascriptEnabled();` for your switched `Àctivity` ?

Comment: I just added it again after switching activities and it made no difference.

Comment: Did you make sure `onWebView().forceJavascriptEnabled();` is called before you're actually trying to perform a search (in your second  `Activity`) ?

Comment: Yes, it was called before the search.

Comment: Good, another question - do you call `reset()` after `perform()` ? For instance, `onWebView().withElement(<some element>).perform(<some action>).reset();`

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `.reset()` at the end of the first interaction;

else you won't be able to access (or match) that reference anymore.

```
onWebView(allOf<View>(isDisplayed(), isJavascriptEnabled()))
    .withElement(findElement(Locator.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[title=Pay]"))
    .perform( ... )
    .reset();
```

as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/web) for Espresso Web states:

> `reset()` reverts the WebView to its initial state. This is necessary when a prior action, such as a click, introduces a navigation change that makes ElementReference and WindowReference objects inaccessible.

then matching again, will provide a new reference, which can be accessed.

Comment: Adding a call to reset() did not help.

Comment: @GaryBak hard to explain it better, while you show only a single instruction of it (which is nothing one could reproduce). I mean, one could even mock `onActivityResult()` with Espresso Intents, which isn't considered here, at all... in such a situation, without the proper test-rule & setup, the second one matcher probably won't even be executed. the `.reset()` only applies to `navigation change` browser events - and is not required, while this won't happen.